# Can these "Promega Wizard genomic DNA Purification kit" be used for samples not stated directly?

Tags: dna, dna-isolation

I am not sure if this is a duplicate of my previous question, it is somewhat related, so sorry if I misunderstood.

The question is, can i use the above kit for samples like hair, fingernails, etc?

Here are the guides:
https://www.promega.com/~/media/files/resources/protcards/wizard%20genomic%20dna%20purification%20kit%20quick%20protocol.pdf

and the extended guide:
https://www.promega.com/~/media/files/resources/protocols/technical%20manuals/0/wizard%20genomic%20dna%20purification%20kit%20protocol.pdf

It says that for the animal tissue:

Animal Tissue (Mouse Liver and Brain), so I figure it wont apply given that these cells might have higher percentage of DNA that hair(roots/shaft) could have, or fingernails.

Comment: You may want to look for forensic kits. These are specially adapted for the needs you habe. But make sure that you have a seat when you read the price quotes, these kits are really expensive. It may be worth to contact a sales representative and tell them that you do a research project and are not a professional analysis lab. Sometimes you can get a good discount then.

Comment: If you have a question about a kit, I strongly suggest contacting the manufacturer instead of just asking random people on the internet.

Comment: In addition, the kit clearly says "DNA". "Genomic RNA" makes little to no sense in a biological context.

Comment: @MarchHo       sorry it was a typo, i fixed it

Comment: It is difficult to isolate good quality genomic DNA from fingernails. PCR for specific genes is much easier. What do you want to do ultimately?

Comment: The column size should be appropriate. And you have to solubilize enough for DNA to come out. But why don't you use kits showing gDNA extraction from nail. http://www.epibio.com/docs/default-source/forum-archive/forum-14-1---pcr-analysis-of-fingernail-dna-using-quickextract-dna-extraction-solution.pdf?sfvrsn=4 And this information may be useful. http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12033-010-9273-6/fulltext.html

Comment: @WYSIWYG         I was going to PCR for specific genes, the CODIS standard 13 loci for the human genome, using extracted DNA from hair or fingernails, thanks for the reply.

Comment: @RoSiv You don't need to extract DNA to do PCR. You can simply use a small part of the sample. Like you do in colony PCR.

Comment: @WYSIWYG          so are you telling me I could just break down the hair/fingernail and then perform PCR on that solution? if so would you have some type of protocol for that?

Comment: @RoSiv See [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20009340) article. And for hair you should use the hair root (that is where you will find viable cells)